# Gnome Calculator problem with pasting from the clipboard

Tags: gnome-calculator

I have a suggestion for an improvement to the Gnome Calculator that comes with Ubuntu.  If you copy a financial value eg from a spreadsheet to the clipboard and paste it into the calculator, the currency symbol gets pasted as well.  Any arithmetic then fails.

Either the currency symbol should be removed from the paste or the Calculator should recognise from the users computer language config what currency symbol is in use and give the result with the currency symbol.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it's not a question about ubuntu but a feature request which should be posted elsewhere.

Comment: You can post the feature request here. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calculator